# Using Fingerprint Reader in Kubuntu 20.04. on Thinkpad T495

Tags: kubuntu, amd-graphics, thinkpad, amd-processor

I installed  a fresh copy of Kubuntu 20.04. on my Thunkpad T495 (AMD CPU + Vega graphics). I can enroll my finger prints with "fprintd-enroll" successfully. So the FP reader works generally. But I cannot see any setting for enabling the FP for login. Where are these settigs? In Ubuntu 20.04. you can do it in user settings, but not in Kubuntu. Doesn't the KDE desktop have these settings at all?

I even tried the manual way and added the line:

```
auth sufficient pam_fprintd.so
```

to:

/etc/pam.d/polkit-1 and
/etc/pam.d/sudo
etc...

However, it does not help. Has anybody an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Install the applications needed:

```
sudo apt install -y fprintd libpam-fprintd
sudo pam-auth-update
```

Once install finishes, open `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` for editing

```
$ sudoedit /etc/pam.d/common-auth
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

And modify the file adding the line shown below in bold. Make sure the order of these lines is the same as shown here.

```
auth [success=2 default=ignore] pam_fprintd.so max_tries=1 timeout=10 
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

Save.

Finally, enroll your fingerprint with the following command:

```
fprintd-enroll $USER
```

After running the command, swipe your finger across the reader 3 times to enroll your fingerprint.

But! Login screen works uncorrected.

Comment: Working for me. Thank you!

Comment: mark the answer as correct then

Comment: Cool, thank you! Works for ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 8 but UX is not very convenient. GUI login screen shows password input field but requires fingerprint, virtual consoles works better and asks only for ringerprint. I've used Macbook Pro and there it is much more comfortable, GUI login screen asks either for password or for fingerprint, both variants are supported and I prefer such UX.

Comment: I could not solve the problem on the login and lock screen, so I turned off this function at all.

Comment: After following your instruction to be impllemented on Kubuntu 21.04 and on ThinkBook 140-IL I arrive at this "list_devices failed: No devices available
"

Comment: Following these instructions, `sudo` works, but if you want to type the password then you have to first CTRL-C the fingerprint prompt. Plasma lockscreen, OTOH, does not work - there's a fingerprint prompt but it fails with "fails to match fingerprint" message every time, and if I try with password only, there's a 10 seconds delay in login while the fingerprint verification times out. Not a great experience.

Comment: Using the instructions from this EndeavourOS form post (https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/how-to-enable-fingerprint-support-in-kde-5-24/24401/6) for setting up a `/etc/pam.d/kde` file, unlocking the screen with fingerprint now works, but using a password login still incurs the fprintd module timeout.

Comment: There is some other information on https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues/284 and https://github.com/sddm/sddm/pull/1220

Comment: Executing `sudo apt install -y fprintd libpam-fprintd && sudo pam-auth-update` is enough in Kubuntu 23.10. Then you can go to *System Settings > Users > Configure Fingerprint Authentication...*